# Want to map over both the file data and the file names of the data source files

Tags: plotting, functions

I have a lot of experimental datafiles I would like to plot first and check, if they can be used for further analysis or not. To avoid importing every single file I used *FileNames* and than mapping. This creates a plot grid, works fine so far.

I would now like to label each of the plots by the *FileBaseName* for quick identification. Is this possible?

Here is what I tried so far:

```
files = FileNames["*.dat", {"path_to_data_directory"}];
data = Import /@ files;

ListLinePlot[#, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
  PlotLabel -> FileBaseName[#] & /@ files] & /@ data
```

As I said, the plotting works perfect, but `PlotLabel` gives labeling of the plots with every single plot is labeled by the base name of the first file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a closer look at what you are doing `f[#, opt -> FileBaseName[#] & /@ {file1, file2}] & /@ {data1, data2}`. Then, take a look at `MapThread`.

Comment: In this case you could just map over the file names `ListLinePlot[Import[#], InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
PlotLabel -> FileBaseName[#]  ] & /@ files`.  (Unless of course you want to keep all the `data` in memory for other purpose.)

Comment: @george2079: This works perfect. The data is still in memory and can be used with the second line of my code. Thank you so much!

Comment: Nevertheless Ill give it a try to the suggestion of @Kuba

Comment: my point is you don't really want to `Import` every file twice, although if the performance is acceptable there is no real harm in it.  Another tack on this is when you import do `data={#,Import[#]}&/@files` , then you are carrying around a list with the data and the associated name together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take kuba's suggestion and make it nice and tidy and name-space non-polluting.

```
Module[{plotF, files, names, data},
  plotF = ListLinePlot[#1, PlotLabel -> #2, InterpolationOrder -> 0] &;
  files = FileNames["*.dat", {"path_to_data_directory"}];
  names = FileBaseName[#] & /@ files;
  data = Import /@ files;
  MapThread[plotF, {data, names}]]
```